# How to protect main/master branch of remote repo using git commands or any other Commands?

Tags: git, bonobo

I am using Bonobo Git Server and i want to protect my main/master branch So, no one can push in master/main branch.

There is no such option in Bonobo Git Server to protect my branch.

This script of per-receive is not working

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    # Check if the branch being pushed is "main"
    if [[ $refname == refs/heads/main ]]; then
       # If not allowed to push to "main", reject the push
       echo "Error: Pushing to 'main' branch is not allowed." >&2
       exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: Did you mean `pre-receive` instead of `per-receive`? What do you mean with it not working? Is it not executed? Does a command fail?

Comment: *Where* is your `pre-receive` script installed?

Answer (score 1):

The hook must be on the server side, **not** where you clone it to.

Assuming your repositories are stored here on the server: go to `~\App_Data\Repositories\<RepositoryName>`

add your hook under **hooks** directory.

You should already have some default hook samples there e.g. : `pre-receive.sample`

put your content into that file and remove *.sample* part of the file.

You should get your hook working.